# Using Guava classes in an Eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, import, guava

In my Eclipse project, I need Matplotlib4j, which in turn needs Guava, which seems to be an Eclipse plugin. For example, in com.github.shOnk.matplotlib4j, there is `import com.google.common.base.Preconditions;`
How can I import guava in matplotlib4j and then import matplotlib4j in my project ?

I have tried to add to add the guava jar to the matplotlib4j project in my workspace, and then exporting it as a jar, but the guava imports fail